# Cut multiple columns if a certain cell in first row/header are the same

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently new to macro VBA and I have been trying to copy a column if the values of a specific rows are the same then paste it on another sheet until all columns are copied and pasted. The purpose of this is to consolidate team members of a team (the team is the value that im trying to look for). It only stops when the next cell to the right is already blank. And I will only find the team members' team on the first row of the sheet only. I placed a code that I found on the Internet and modified it but it only copies the last DATA team it finds. Thank you.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
Dim colName As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values")

With ws
    Set aCell = .Range("A1:XFD1").Find(What:="DATA", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

aCell.EntireColumn.Cut

Sheets("Team").Columns("D:W").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Else
MsgBox "Team not found"

End If
End With
```

Comment: If you don't have that much data you could run a basic loop through your sheet, can you give an example of a process that would occur?

Comment: Do you look only for one value for the team you look for or do you look for different teams

Comment: @Pierre44 I look only for the value on the first row only. The whole first row contains the team name and I am tryin to look for that team names and merge them on another sheet. It should copy the whole column and contains 1 team per sheet. The code that I provided just came from the internet and I just modified it.

Comment: @Lutscha I would like to provide an excel file but I don't know how to attach it here. Sorry, this is my first time to ask something on stackoverflow

Comment: If i understand it right you have some sheet with different team names in first row. And You want to copy columns for each distinct team name to different sheet. 
What you could do is to create array of distinct team names by looping through first row of your sheet. Then add new sheets based on this team names array and then just loop row with team names on first sheet and copy each row to sheet with corresponding team name.

Comment: @Sphinx Yes that's what I've been trying to do but how will you do it by not looking for the team names. Like in the future if a new team is to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCols()

    Dim ArrTeams() As String, Team As String
    Dim TeamCounter As Long, LastCol As Long, FirstCol As Long, i As Long, LastColDest As Long
    Dim SrcWs As Worksheet
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set SrcWs = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ReDim ArrTeams(1 To 1)
    With Wb        
        With SrcWs
            'find last column with team
            LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            TeamCounter = 1
            FirstCol = 1 'or whatever your first column with teams is

            'loop all columns in row 1
            For i = FirstCol To LastCol
                If .Cells(1, i) <> "" Then
                    Team = .Cells(1, i)
                    If Not IsInArray(Team, ArrTeams) Then 'take only unique team names
                        ReDim Preserve ArrTeams(1 To TeamCounter)
                        ArrTeams(TeamCounter) = Team
                        TeamCounter = TeamCounter + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End With

        'create new sheet for each team
        For i = 1 To UBound(ArrTeams)
            .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Sheets.Item(.Sheets.Count).Name = ArrTeams(i)
        Next i

         With SrcWs
            'loop all columns in row 1
            For i = FirstCol To LastCol
                If .Cells(1, i) <> "" Then
                    Team = .Cells(1, i)
                    With Wb.Sheets(Team)
                        'find last non empty column on destination sheet
                        LastColDest = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    End With
                    .Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy
                    Wb.Sheets(Team).Cells(1, LastColDest + 1).PasteSpecial
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

  IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))

End Function
```

It should loop all columns on `"Sheet1"` starting in `FirstCol` and ending in `LastCol`, take unique team names from first row. Create new sheet for each unique team name. Copy entire column for each unique team name to coresponding sheet. 
 
Just remember that it will allways add new sheets so if you want to run it multiple times then there should be check if sheet with specific name already exists. 
 
EDIT

Add
`Dim LastRow As Long, j As Long` 
And 
`Dim  TargetWs As Worksheet` 
in declaration part at begining 
Change loop for adding new sheets to

```
For i = 1 To UBound(ArrTeams)
    .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    .Sheets.Item(.Sheets.Count).Name = ArrTeams(i)
    .Sheets(ArrTeams(i)).Range("A2:A1000").FormulaR1C1 = _ 
    "=SUM(RC[2]:RC[" & .Sheets(ArrTeams(i)).Columns.Count - 1 & "])"
Next i
```

at the end add

```
For i = LBound(ArrTeams) To UBound(ArrTeams)
    Team = ArrTeams(i) 'team name and also sheet name
    Set TargetWs = .Sheets(Team)
    With TargetWs
        .Calculate 'calculate SUM formula on each sheet 
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data in column "A"
        For j = LastRow To 2 Step -1 'assuming that in row 1 there is some header
            If .Cells(j, "A") = 0 Then
                .Cells(j, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next j
    End With
Next i
```

This should do the trick as long as you don't have more than 1000 rows of data. If so you can adjust SUM formula to cover more rows or find last row with data on each "Team" sheet and adjust formula in loop.

Comment: Hi, you almost got it but when copying columns it should copy the whole columns. The code you generated, I was not sure of the logic but it seems that it stops once it detects a blank cell, it only copy from first row until the last non-empty cell. It should push through with the non-empty cells because some columns has values after empty cells. Thank very much for your help

Comment: I've assumed that in first row you have team name. Code is looping this first row and if there is an empty cell it skips this cell couse there is no 'team name'. It will loop all cells in row 1 to the last non empty cell in row 1. 
Maybe you could post some printscreen of youre source data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Sphinx this is what I have so far. And I modified the code you have given and added something to it. The syntax that I do not have is on how to delete a row when a specific cell on column C has 0 value. And it should work on all ArrTeams(i) sheets only. Thank you for you help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8NS8.png

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCols()

Dim ArrTeams() As String, Team As String
Dim TeamCounter As Long, LastCol As Long, FirstCol As Long, i As Long, LastColDest As Long
Dim SrcWs As Worksheet
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim LastRowColumnD As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set SrcWs = Wb.Sheets("Values")
ReDim ArrTeams(1 To 1)
With Wb
    With SrcWs
        'find last column with team
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        TeamCounter = 1
        FirstCol = 1 'or whatever your first column with teams is

        'loop all columns in row 1
        For i = FirstCol To LastCol
            If .Cells(1, i) <> "" Then
                Team = .Cells(1, i)
                If Not IsInArray(Team, ArrTeams) Then 'take only unique team names
                    ReDim Preserve ArrTeams(1 To TeamCounter)
                    ArrTeams(TeamCounter) = Team
                    TeamCounter = TeamCounter + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    'create new sheet for each team
    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrTeams)
        .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Sheets.Item(.Sheets.Count).Name = ArrTeams(i)
        Sheets("Values").Columns("A:C").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(ArrTeams(i)).Range("A1:C1")
Range("A1").Value = " "
Range("B1").Value = " "
Range("C1").Value = " "
Range("A2").Value = "Team:"
Range("B2").Value = ArrTeams(i)
Range("C2").Value = " "
Range("B2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("B2").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("A2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("A2").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
LastRowColumnD = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C4:C" & LastRowColumnD).Formula = "=sum(D4:XFD4)"


    Next i

     With SrcWs
        'loop all columns in row 1
        For i = FirstCol To LastCol
            If .Cells(1, i) <> "" Then
                Team = .Cells(1, i)
                With Wb.Sheets(Team)
                    'find last non empty column on destination sheet
                    LastColDest = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                End With
                .Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy
                Wb.Sheets(Team).Cells(1, LastColDest + 1).PasteSpecial
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End With




Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))

End Function
```

Comment: This is easy. If you always have sum in column A then you just need to loop backwards on this column, check if there i 0 or no and if it is delete row. To do this add another loop  at the end of your code. Use ArrTeams array to loop all new worksheets, on each worksheet find last cell with value on column A, loop this column backwards from last cell to first with value. That's all. Try to write some code and post it back if any problems.

Comment: Hi @Sphinx I am trying to filter it out buy selecting the needed sheets but it only filters the activesheet not the whole selected sheet.

Comment: Dim s As Long
    Sheet1.Select
    For s = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(s).Name <> "PivotTable" And Sheets(s).Name <> "Button"  And Sheets(s).Name <> "Table" And Sheets(s).Name <> "Task" And Sheets(s).Name <> "Mapping" Then Sheets(s).Select Replace:=False
    Next s
    
    Range("C:C").Select
    
    Dim sheet As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each sheet In selectedRange.Cells
        ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$C$500").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
    Next sheet